# Count ways to place $n$ identical balls into $n$ urns so that exactly one urn is empty?

Tags: probability

> How many ways are there to plane n indistinguishable balls into n urns so that exactly one urn is empty?

Why is the answer for this question n(n-1)?

Comment: Because you have $n$ ways of choosing which one is empty, and then you have $n-1$ ways to distribute the other balls.

Comment: Are you implying that the *urns* are distinguishable by leaving out that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter which urn is empty, and there are $n$ urns, so we have $n$ choices of which urn to leave empty.

Next, every other urn must have at least one ball in it (since we can only have one empty urn), so must distribute $n-1$ of the balls into these $n-1$ urns.  We have one ball left and we can choose any of those $n-1$ urns to put the last ball into (it cannot go into the empty urn, or it would no longer be empty).

Thus, we have $n$ choices of which urn is empty, and then $n-1$ choices of where to place the extra ball, giving $n \cdot (n-1)$ total ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is the maximal number of balls in a urn when the condition is satisfied, and how many urns will have the maximal number? Say you choose the urn having zero balls first. How many different choices do you have? Then, given that you have already chosen the urn with zero balls: how many choices do you have for the urns with the maximal amount of balls?